# Change the color of a floating label from bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 to create a form with floating input.
Here is an input I use:

```
<div class="form-floating mx-auto mb-3 w-25">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username_field" placeholder=" " />
    <label for="username_field" class="form-label">Username</label>
</div>
```

This code generate a floating input like so:
[floating input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ug3N.png)
I would like to change the color of the label when the input is selected (using only css, if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following to affect all inputs or modify the following to use id's/classes if you only want it specifically for this one input:

```
input:focus + label {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When it will be focus on your input element, at the time of focus use + selector to select the label next to it and give whatever color to it you want.
Read it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) about selectors.

if you need something else, pls feel free to comment

```css
.form-control:focus + .form-label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-floating mx-auto mb-3 mt-3 w-75">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username_field" placeholder=" " />
    <label for="username_field" class="form-label">Username</label>
</div>
```